# How to read correctly european characters (from file and command shell) in C++?

Tags: c++, string, io, ascii

In my program I'm reading a text file using ifstream for opening it using stringstream for reading each line (using getline for tokenize); when I get an european character, like "è", it saves this character with "├¿", and this works as expected, because I'm using string and not wstring.
But when I get a line from cmd (I'm using Windows) the word "è" is saved as "è" inside the string. My objective is to compare strings read from file and from command shell, but if they are encoded in different ways I'm stucked, because "è".compare("├¿") is naturally != 0. I would like to have both "wrong" or both correct, because my aim is not showing them but just counting occurrencies. I'm programming using latest version of Code::Blocks, with MinGW 32-bit and gcc 4.7.1

UPDATE (code)

```
ifstream file;
stringstream stream;

file.open(path);

while( file ){

    while( getline(file,line) ){

        it = 1;
        stream << line;

        if( line.compare("")!=0 ){
            while( getline(stream,token,'\t')) {

                if( it == 1 ){
                    ID = atoi( token.c_str() );
                }
                if( it == 2 ){
                    word = token;

                    if( !case_sensitive ){
                        word = get_lower_case( word );
                    }
                }
                if( it == tags_index ){
                    pos = token;
                }

                it++;
            }

            data.push_back(make_row(ID,word,pos));
        }

        stream.clear();
    }
}
```

This is part of the function I use to read file (I have a struct for store each entry of a tabulated file, my problem is with "word").

```
getline(cin,sentence);

[...]

stringstream stream;
string token;
vector<string> tokens;

stream << sentence;
while( getline(stream,token,' ') ){
    tokens.push_back(token);
}
stream.clear();
```

This is how I read the input stream in the command shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting (imbuing) the locale

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    auto loc = std::locale("it_IT"); // Example: Italian locale
    std::cin.imbue(loc); // imbue it to input stream, can use a fstream here
    std::cout.imbue(loc); // imbue it to output stream

    // rest of the program
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I've tried to put that snippet at the beginning of my code, but it seems that the problem is still there; when I compare the two string, I still get a different value for them.

Comment: @AndreaRomagnoli can you try changing the locale to the one of the language you use? E.g., `std::locale("it_IT")` I am not sure how well supported locales are by gcc, they work in clang though

Comment: I tried, but it gives me runtime error; looking around on the web it seems that on gcc in windows is only accepted "C" and "". In fact I tried "it_IT", "it_IT.UTF-8" and even "en_EN" and "en_EN.UTF-8" doesn't work.

Comment: @AndreaRomagnoli yes, same happens on my end on OS X with gcc. clang works fine though, you can try switching the compiler  http://www.bencode.net/blog/2012/10/20/clangonwindows/

Comment: Ok, I'm going to grab a new compiler and do the setup, I'll post here if it will work.

Comment: I've setup MSVC 12.0, and doing cout << loc.name(); it shows "Italian_Italy.1252", that seems ok (with gcc I had only "C"). Unfortunately the problem's still there.

Comment: I don't know why this happens, unfortunately I am not too familiar with internationalization, perhaps you'll get a good answer from someone here

Comment: @AndreaRomagnoli One more thing... are you imbuing the locale to the `fstream` also? i.e., must also do `file.imbue(...)` so the `fstream` uses the same locale, or you can try setting the global locale only once (`std::locale::global(your_locale)`), without the need for further imbuing

Comment: Something happened setting to global: input strings are not correct anymore (instead of "è" i get "s" for example), and for fstream ones i got the same strange symbol for every different accent.